# How to use tflite model coverted from TFMarianMTModel on huggingface

Tags: nlp, tensorflow-lite, transformer-model

I am looking for a en-zh translate model that can be used in TFLite, and i found one on huggingface: https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-zh

I have coverted the model to .tflite by follow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFMarianMTModel, AutoTokenizer

print("loading model...")
model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-zh'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = TFMarianMTModel.from_pretrained(model_name, from_pt=True)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model);
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert();

with open("./out/tf_model.tflite", 'wb') as o_:
    o_.write(tflite_model)
```

but when i try to use it for infrence, i meet some problem:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-zh'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
result = tokenizer(">>cmn_Hans<< hello world", return_tensors="tf", padding=True)

print("tokenize result: ", result, '\n')

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="./out/tf_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_ids = result["input_ids"]

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], input_ids)
interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print("output_data:", output_data)
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lite.py", line 48, in <module>
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], input_ids)
  File "/Users/xuanyue/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 607, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 1 but expected 3 for dimension 0 of input 2.
```

I try to resize the shape, but i don't know how to do that, any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? @Pan

Comment: @GokulNC no, i have no idea.